# .Net Micro Framework Emulator : change value returned by SystemInfo.SystemID.Model

Tags: c#, .net, emulation, .net-micro-framework

I'm trying to make an emulator for [FEZ](http://www.tinyclr.com) and their implementation throws an exception if the value returned by `SystemInfo.SystemID.Model` is not what's expected (1 in my case)

Is there a way to modify the value returned by SystemInfo.SystemID.Model for the applications running inside my emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Model is marked with `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` which calls into native code (i.e the CLR itself). For a .NET Micro device this will probably be the low level firmware controlled by GHI for the Fez device.

Your best option would be to contact GHI and raise a request for a hook point to be added to their custom components to prevent the exception if running inside the emulator.